# Ideas Related to Subset Sum with 2,3 and more integers

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, data-structures, subset-sum

I've been struggling with this problem just like everyone else and I'm quite sure there has been more than enough posts to explain this problem. However in terms of understanding it fully, I wanted to share my thoughts and get more efficient solutions from all the great people in here related to **Subset Sum** problem.

I've searched it over the Internet and there is actually a lot sources but I'm really willing to re-implement an algorithm or finding my own in order to understand fully.

The key thing I'm struggling with is the **efficiency** considering the set size will be large. (I do not have a limit, just conceptually large). The two phases I'm trying to implement ideas on is finding **two** numbers that are equal to given integer **T**, finding **three** numbers and eventually **K** numbers. Some ideas I've though;

For the **two** integer part I'm thing basically sorting the array **O(nlogn)** and for each element in the array searching for its negative value. (i.e if the array element is **3** searching for **-3**). Maybe a hash table inclusion could be better, providing a **O(1)** indexing the element?

For the **three or more** integers I've found an amazing blog post;http://www.skorks.com/2011/02/algorithms-a-dropbox-challenge-and-dynamic-programming/. However even the author itself states that it is not applicable for large numbers.

So I was for **2** and **3 and more** integers what ideas could be applied for the subset problem. I'm struggling with setting up a dynamic programming method that will be efficient for the large inputs as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That [blog post](http://www.skorks.com/2011/02/algorithms-a-dropbox-challenge-and-dynamic-programming/) you linked to looked pretty great, actually.  This is, after all, an NP-complete problem...

But I bet you could speed it up even further.  I haven't done any benchmarks, but I'm gonna guess that his use of a matrix is his single biggest time sink.  First, it'll take a huge amount of memory for some really trivial inputs (For example: [-1000, 1000] will need 2001 columns!  Good grief!), and then you're wasting a ton of cycles scanning through each row looking for `"T"`s, which are often gonna be pretty sparse.

So instead:  Use a "set" data structure.  That'll keep space and iteration time to a minimum,* but store values just as well:  If it's in the set, it's a `"T"`; otherwise, it's an `"F"`.

Hope that helps!

*:  Of course, "minimum" doesn't necessarily = "small."

Comment: An additional question: Would the blog post way would be considered as successful in a Skype interview? :D The reason why I have written this question detail is that I'm afraid of being asked that "this solution is too custom, you should provide a more general one".

Comment: @rolandbishop - I'd say that the only thing that keeps the blog's solution from being "general enough" is his use of the matrix.  His sample set of `[1, -3, 2, 4]` uses 11 columns (the minimum).  But that same exact set multiplied by ten (`[10, -30, 20, 40]`) uses 101 (`-30...70`)!  Multiply by ten again, and...  well, you see where this is going.  Using a "set" data structure avoids that wasted storage (and thus also wasted looping) - the only thing I can see that keeps the original from being a "general enough" solution.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for all the help! You've enlightened me.